# Получение аннотации Enum по индексу ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Как получить аннотацию Enum по индексу. Я получаю индекс 1. И хотел бы вывести на VIEW результат, чтобы выводилось "Брестская".

```
public enum Region
        {
            [Display(Name = "Брестская")]
            Brest = 1,
            [Display(Name = "Витебская")]
            Vitebsk = 2,
            [Display(Name = "Гомельская")]
            Gomel = 3,
            [Display(Name = "Гродненская")]
            Grodno = 4,
            [Display(Name = "Минская")]
            Minsk = 5,
            [Display(Name = "Могилевская")]
            Mogilev = 6
        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать перечесления просто через запятую. Тогда в бд запишется число, а на выводе будет слово

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц в бд записывается индекс, но как обратно по индексу получить значение? Именно то, которое указано в аннотации.

Comment: Просто попытайтесь вывести с помощью клнтекста

Comment: Как как - рефлексия. GetCustomAttributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum Region
{
    [Display(Name = "Брестская")]
    Brest = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Витебская")]
    Vitebsk = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Гомельская")]
    Gomel = 3,
    [Display(Name = "Гродненская")]
    Grodno = 4,
    [Display(Name = "Минская")]
    Minsk = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Могилевская")]
    Mogilev = 6
}

public static class EnumDisplayExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        //определяем тип параметра и извлекаем массив его публичных членов по имени
        MemberInfo[] memberInfo = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString());

        //определяем тип класса атрибута
        Type attributeType = typeof(DisplayAttribute);

        //у первого публичного члена пытаемся получить массив
        //атрибутов типа DisplayAttribute
        object[] attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, false);
        //если поиск безуспешен или почему-то таких атрибутов найдено больше одного
        //вываливаем ошибку
        if (attributes == null || attributes.Length != 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Невозможно найти атрибут по имени '{nameof(DisplayAttribute)}'");

        //хватаем атрибут
        var attribute = attributes.SingleOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
        //возвращаем значение его свойства по имени Name
        return attribute?.Name;      
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int index = 1;

        Region region = (Region)index;
        string displayName = region.GetDisplayName();

        Console.WriteLine(displayName);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если уж используете `as`, то есть предполагаете `null` как результат, то возвращайте `attribute?.Name`)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov и то верно.

Comment: @Bulson Было бы очень хорошо, если бы вы добавили комментарии.

Comment: @Дмитрий, вроде сделал. Так пойдет?